# Function in function Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Task: to write a function foo.

```
function arg1(a,b) {
    return a + b;
}
var x = foo(arg1, arg2);
x(arg3); // return arg2 + arg3
var y = foo(arg1, arg2, arg3);
y(); // return arg2 + arg3
```

I can't understand how at first `var x, y` - numbers ( because arg1() return number ), and then `x, y` - functions. How is it possible?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is `foo`?  `arg1` *is* a variable, it's also a function.  What is `arg2` and `arg3`?  Can you explain this a bit more?  What works, doesn't work?  What do you want to do?  What does this do?

Comment: @RocketHazmat he want `x` to be a function and he don't have `foo` so he want a higher order function.

Comment: Tried to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is higher order function [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), a function that will return another function

```
function add(a,b) {
    return a + b;
}

function curry(fun) {
   var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
   args.shift();
   return function() {
       return fun.apply(null, args.concat([].slice(arguments)));
   };
}

x = curry(add, 10, 20);
x();
```

if you want to add more then two arguments you need to rewrite add function, you can iterate or use another higher order function reduce.

```
function add() {
   [].slice.call(null, arguments).reduce(function(a, b) { return a+b; });
}
```

Or you can use @PaulS. solution using reduce in your foo function to call it to more then one argument:

```
function foo(fun) {
   var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
   args.shift();
   return function() {
      return args.concat([].slice.call(arguments)).reduce(fun);
   };
};

var x = foo(add, 10, 20, 30);
x(30);
```

Comment: I wrote a load of code and yours now looks somewhat similar (except I used `reduce`), but I can't post because the question got closed -__-, but yes, I believe this is what they were looking for, +1

Comment: @PaulS. Just added `add` function using reduce, before I read your comment.

Comment: my placement of reduce was `generatorArgs.concat(args).reduce(func);`

Comment: @PaulS. added your solution.

Comment: @jcubic. Where can I read about it?

Comment: @user54264 it's called functional programming, here is article about it in javascript http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg25/index.html you can search for more using google.